# How to use multiple UINavgationController within one project in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I am using `Xib` instead of storyboard and using this code in my `AppDelegate` to perform navigation in my project

```
var nav = UINavigationController()
let FirstVC = HomeScreenVIewController(nibName: "HomeScreenVIewController", bundle: nil) as HomeScreenVIewController
nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstVC)
nav.navigationBarHidden = true
self.window?.rootViewController = nav
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()    
nav.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

To navigate from one view to other on button click I am using this code

```
let NextVc = RegistrationStepOneViewController(nibName: "RegistrationStepOneViewController", bundle: nil) as RegistrationStepOneViewController
appDelegate.nav.pushViewController(NextVc, animated: true)
```

This navigation will go for all registration process steps. When registration is completed there is a dashboard screen from where user can not navigate back to registration steps(obviously).

Now I want another navigation to start from dashboard and go futher in the application. How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Probably easiest to keep the one navigation controller and just remove all of the previous entries from its `viewControllers` property array

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please explain with example

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setViewControllers: animated: method to replace the current navigation stack with whatever stack you'd like.

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([yourNewRootVC], animated: true)
```

The above, for example, would give you a new root controller and would blow up your current nav stack.

Having said that, with the situation you are describing, I would recommend launching the app with the main view controller as the root of your nav VC, then presenting (animated: false) the registration flow over that. Then you just need to dismiss it once registration is complete or not present it at all if registration has already happened. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: can you please guide me about exact syntax because its giving me error. I am using swift 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
 let vc: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    let view: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
    vc.view = view
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    let arr: [UIViewController] = [vc as UIViewController]
    self.navigationController!.setViewControllers(arr, animated: true)
```

You can set array of `viewcontrollers` to navigation controller. You can add multiple array to that arr and can use same navigation controller.